# Private and public header files in Visual Studio (CMake based project)

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017

Consider the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(mylib
    src/mylib.cpp
    src/mylibprivate.h
    header/mylib.h
)

target_include_directories(mylib
    INTERFACE header
    PRIVATE src
)
```

So I've got one private header and one public header.

Visual Studio, to my knowledge, doesn't have that notion of private and public headers in it's Solution Explorer, though. It only has "Source Files" and "Header Files" folder per "project".

What are the best practices in imposing that notion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Source Files" and "Header Files" are default groups created by `cmake`.  To add a specific file to a new group use [source_group()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/source_group.html), e.g. `source_group(private src/mylibprivate.h)`.  Alternatively if you do not include `src/mylibprivate.h` in the project then Visual Studio will add it under a different folder where external header files go (same place `stdio.h` goes).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to understand if there's a way to "split" the "Header Files" section to private and public ones (in Visual Studio), or even just display those private headers under the "Source Files".

Comment: It should be the same command. Just specify the group or subgroup you want to put the file into.